# Php Allowable uploaded file extension

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I only allow certain filetypes on upload in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486329/how-can-i-only-allow-certain-filetypes-on-upload-in-php)

i'm learning PHp and Mysql. I want to create a function that allow only specific file extension which uploaded by user. Like..

```
$whitelist = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png","bmp","pdf" );
```

So how do i check this specific file extension with php. Can anyone tell me please..
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an option:

```
function checkFormat($source){
    $whitelist = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png","bmp","pdf" );
    $type="";
    if(version_compare('4.3.0', PHP_VERSION) > 0){
        $type=mime_content_type($source['tmp_name']);
    }else{
        $type=$source['type'];
    }

    return (in_array($type, $whitelist));
}
```

Regards!

Comment: one needs to say you need to call `checkFormat($_FILES["fieldname"])`

Comment: $source means $_FILE['file']['tmp_name']; ?

Comment: no `$source` means `$_FILES["file"]`

Comment: What does mean by only...$_FILES['file'] ?

Comment: @user1295995 Check http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php. $source is the associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method. In your form must exist an input named "file", like <input type="file" name="file" />

Answer (score 2):

Get the file extension of the uploaded file with [`pathinfo`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/pathinfo) like

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

and then check against a whitelist of allowed exentsions

```
$allowedExtensions = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png","bmp","pdf");
$isAllowed = in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions);
```

maybe you need to modify the extension recognize function to get some special extensions like tar.gz, but that should do the trick.

*Edit:* As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133896/finding-extension-of-the-file-being-uploaded-using-php) you shouldn't check the file extension, but the mime-type.

Comment: Forget explode, there is [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo) ;)

Comment: hakre: you're the man ! :) my method was rather "quick and dirty" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
 http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

It provides an example that shows how to do it.

Comment: Obligatory http://w3fools.com/